# Publishing Queue Shows "Success" however page doesn't get published

Tags: publishing

While publishing the `HTML` or `ASPX` type page to my one of the targets (staging) it immediately gives `success` message (which means publisher not getting anything to publish), however when publishing same page to LIVE or any other target is goes properly. I can see the proper publication transaction. XML type page works fine on both the targets.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Before Publishing to Staging (in the Publish dialog), can you press the button "Show Items to Publish", does it actually return a result there? An empty Publish Transaction will go to Success immediately, as described [here](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/emptypublishtransactionseventhandler.aspx) that can have multiple causes.

Comment: Yes the result is appearing on both the cases, staging and live.

Comment: it is getting successful published on other targets, only behaving differently for staging targets and it was getting published till yesterday

Comment: you are getting items to be published while clicking "Show Items to Publish" for staging as suggested by Brat? do you have any custom resolver in place?

Comment: why does custom resolver will behave differently for specific target and which was working till yesterday

Comment: let me tell you, the Resolver could behave differently for a specific publishing target if programmed so. And even if it shows items to publish in GUI, it could end up no items in the output package (if publisher is a separate machine and resolver is deployed only to publisher machine.) . I can explain the scenario in detail if you want.

Comment: @user007 if you are seeing resolved items in the "Show Items to Publish" list, then there will be items rendered. The only other option then is that something is not being deployed or removed there. Check the Publish Transaction itself (open it and view the Publishing Process Details and number of Processed Items, be sure to check Show Successful too) and update your question with its details (or a screenshot of it).

Comment: Yes all verified, there is nothing in publication transaction..checked successfull section as well. Most confusing it was working till yesterday and publishing was fine..I can see XML type pages are getting published successfull..only HTML, ASPX etc. page are behaving like this.

Comment: Ensure no-one has set the Structure Group 'publishable' to unchecked. I've come a cropper with this before!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the more confusing things that Tridion does. Once you know how it works it's fine, but you have to know.

So... when you ask Tridion to publish something for you, it figures out what should get published. This is called resolving. The result of resolving can be seen if you click the "see items to publish" button in the publish dialog.

Anyway - if the list of "things to publish" determined by resolving is empty, then publishing will succeed very easily. Tridion will tell you straight away - Yes, I have published all the (zero) things I should have, and none of them failed, so that represents success.

Why might some things not resolve? The first thing I'd look for in your situation is whether the item is already published. The publish dialog has a check-box for this. Something like "Only publish items that are already published". This (quite correctly) is the default.

This is where one publication target can be different to another. If you're publishing to  STAGING, and the items in question have never been published there before, unless you specify "items that aren't already published" (or whatever the wording is), the currently not-published items will not feature in the resolving results, so you'll end up publishing nothing.... which will succeed very quickly

Comment: There is also another scenario where the 'publishable' option make be UNchecked also - this can be even more confusing as it's hidden in the Structure Group properties (unless you use a naming convention). Checkout the extension that may be of use here ... https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/emptypublishtransactionseventhandler.aspx

Comment: Yes - however this would affect both targets equally. That's why my answer focuses on the "republish" scenario. But definitely worth mentioning. Thanks.