# Publishing Issue: Default Resolver not resolving from Page

Tags: 2011, publishing, razormediator

When i publish page, Publishing queue shows success but nothing is delivered to file system. Its happening with all the pages which were working fine earlier.

I do not have any event-handler, Custom resolver configured.

DCP publishing is working fine.

I tried following:

1. Tried running publisher in debug mode, it says nothing is published.

> ```
> 07:51:00.8838 <3300> Deployment feedback handler thread started.
>     07:51:01.4728 <3288> Listening for messages on PublishQueue.
>     07:51:01.4728 <3296> Listening for messages on DeployQueue.
>     07:51:51.7289 <3288> Retrieved queue message 1778609 from PublishQueue
>     07:51:51.7319 <3284> Working on queue message 1778609
>     07:51:52.2189 <3284> Handling Publish Transaction [tcm:0-962432-66560]
>     07:51:52.4459 <3284> Publishing item [tcm:185-159562-64] from publication [tcm:0
>     -185-1] to target [tcm:0-12-65537]
>     07:51:52.6809 <3284> Storage location: c:\Temp\tcm_0-962432-66560.Content\
>     07:51:52.8750 <3284> Using resolver [Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving
>     .PageResolver]
>     07:51:52.9280 <3284> Resolving the pages [tcm:185-159562-64] took 00:00:00.04518
>     25
>     07:51:52.9300 <3284> Page tcm:185-159562-64 resolved to 0 items. Resolving took:
>      00:00:00.0908613
>     07:51:52.9530 <3284> Updating the publish transaction with the list of processed
>      items
>     07:51:53.0060 <3284> The number of processed items is zero, don't send an empty
>     transport package
>     07:51:53.0090 <3284> Deleting the transport package.
>     07:51:53.0320 <3284> Handling Publish Transaction [tcm:0-962432-66560] took: 00:
>     00:00.8141000
> ```

2. i checked "Show items to publish" in Publish window, it shows no item.
3. Verified cms config,
4. Referred similar [issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/publishing-queue-shows-success-however-page-doesnt-get-published)

I will appreciate any pointers/help

Comment: Can you check if the Structure group has the checkbox on for Publishable?

Comment: When you checked "Show items to publish" in Publish window, and it shows no items, then your issue is not with Publishing (or its configuration), but with what you are trying to publish. Or you might have a custom resolver or event system enabled that is removing items before the default resolver is executed. Lets start with **editing your question** and **adding** the exact steps of what you are doing.

Comment: @jarnohenneman its there

Comment: @BartKoopman its default Tridion Page publishing, No event-system and custom resolver are configured in my system. few hours back everything was working fine.

Comment: @jarnohenneman: somehow Home SG's checkbox was unchecked. if you move your comments to answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if the Structure group **(HOME)** has the checkbox on for Publishable?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this issue earlier with SDL Tridion 2011 GA version.

For me it got resolved if I make some edit in the page and publish them.

I would suggest that you change something in the page (like changing the order of the component presentations, some metadata etc.) and then try publish.

Usually I experienced with 2011, if there is no change in the component or page and if we try to publish, nothing happens apart from a success message in the publishing queue.

Comment: I agree with Pankaj on this, as recently we faced same issue and we solved it the same way.